# MYSQL accepts only root accounts

Tags: mysql, apache2, phpmyadmin, lamp

I've got a real big problem. I have LAMP on my computer. When I try to connect to mysql not with root account (via phpmyadmin) - phpmyadmin says that it cannot connect to mysql. So, I can connect to mysql only via root.

Comment: It's all OK. I've created mysql accounts. It actually MYSQL account.

Comment: Ask and answer please. Don't put your answer in your question. You can answer your own question, and even accept it.

Comment: I can't because I have less than 100 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in stupid users %. I've had three bad users with name '%'. I've killed them - now it's all OK.

Answer (score 4):

Check the mysql.users table for proper permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Did you actually make the accoutn you're trying to use? Computer-user accounts != mysql accounts. This might seem to be the case is you gave your mysql root user the same password as your normal root account, but nevertheless they are different entities

Answer (score 2):

And if you've recently added any users, you may have to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Check out the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for more details.